# How to make function on related form in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

in my html page there are three form input has been relataed each other.
first input as combobox with option:

- TCA
- Intasept
  second and third input as text type.

if first input fill is "TCA" when user input in second input "01" so in third input automaticly filled by "1-120".
if first input fill is "intasept" when user input in second input "01" in third input automaticly fille by "1-32".

on simple logic.

- first input = "TCA" (selected option by user).
- second input = "01" (manually input by user).
- third input = "1-120" (automaticly input).

this will continue with interval 120. ex:

- second input: 02:      03 and so on.
- third input : 121-240: 241-360 and so on.

if in first input = Intasept (selected option by user).

- second input = 01 (manually input by user).
- third input = 1-32 (automaticly input).
- this will continue with interval 32.

ex:

- second input : 02:    03    and so on.
- third input  : 32-64: 65-96  and so on.
  help me how to make this function in javascript.

Comment: Did you try something on your own?

Comment: not finish yet...i still try

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, this simple script will do it:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var interval, step;
    $("input[name=firstComboBox]").change(function(e) {
        if (this.checked)
            interval = { // map of input value attributes to interval values
                "TCA": 120,
                "intasept": 32
            }[this.value];
        update();
    });
    $("#secondInput").on("change keyup input paste", function(e) {
        step = parseInt(this.value, 10);
        update();
    });
    function update() {
        if (isNaN(interval) || isNaN(step)) return;
        $("#thirdInput").val((interval*step+1)+"-"+(interval*step+interval));
    }
});
```

[Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/prhqL/)

You might not use jQuery but something else to wait for domready and attaching events, and you might need to adapt it for your actual DOM structure (input names/ids), but it should give you an idea how it should be done.

Comment: ok great idea, now my focus how to make this value start 01-32 when user input "1" in second input for intasept and 01-120 for TCA

Comment: i modified this code to be like this http://jsfiddle.net/Y8Y3w/
and this script not run, what wrong?

Comment: I have no idea what `if (this.option: selected)` was supposed to do. From a `<select>` box, you can just get the `.value` attribute (or you'd get the `.selectedIndex`, and then get the respective `<option>` from `.options`). Here's the working update: http://jsfiddle.net/Y8Y3w/3/